# Only return selected fields in Web API results

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a model that contains many more values than my web API consumers need.

```
public class Publication
{
    [Key]
    public int PublicationID { get; set; }
    public string PublicationTitle { get; set; }
    public string Frequency { get; set; }
    public DateTime NextIssueDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime SpaceDeadline { get; set; }
    public DateTime MaterialsDeadline { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDt { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDt { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

I only want say a few of the fields to be passed in the API. I've tried this code but instead of leaving out say UpdateBy in the JSON result, it returns it with a null value. How do I get rid of that?

```
    public IQueryable<Publication> GetPublications()
    {
        return db.Publications
            .ToList()
            .Select(p => new Publication {
                PublicationID = p.PublicationID,
                PublicationTitle = p.PublicationTitle,
                Frequency = p.Frequency,
                NextIssueDate = p.NextIssueDate
            })
            .AsQueryable();
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you're returning a collection of `Publication` objects so you will get every property that is contained in that class, whether you populate it or not. If you want to return a subset of the properties then create a class that has only the properties you want to return and create an instance of that class in your query.

```
public IQueryable<WhatIReallyWantToReturn> GetPublications()
{
    return db.Publications
        .ToList()
        .Select(p => new WhatIReallyWantToReturn {
            PublicationID = p.PublicationID,
            PublicationTitle = p.PublicationTitle,
            Frequency = p.Frequency,
            NextIssueDate = p.NextIssueDate
        })
        .AsQueryable();
}

private class WhatIReallyWantToReturn
{
    public int PublicationID { get; set; }
    public string PublicationTitle { get; set; }
    public string Frequency { get; set; }
    public DateTime NextIssueDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Converting a queryable to enumerable (through the ToList()) and then back to queryable has no meaning. Omit the .ToList() and .AsQueryable(), and you have your result mapped to your new class directly from db

Answer (score 12):

Don't serialize your DAO. Create a complete contract and then serialize it selectively. To creating different contracts for different cases, you could simplify it using Json.Net; you could just create a custom contract resolver and use it as a parameter of SerializeObject() like so

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var person = new TestContract {FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", Age = 36};

    var firstNameContract = new SelectiveSerializer("firstname");
    var allPropertiesContract = new SelectiveSerializer("firstname, lastname, age");

    var allJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        person, 
        Formatting.Indented,
        new JsonSerializerSettings {ContractResolver = allPropertiesContract});

    var firstNameJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        person, 
        Formatting.Indented,
        new JsonSerializerSettings {ContractResolver = firstNameContract});

    Console.WriteLine(allJson);
    //  {
    //    "FirstName": "John",
    //    "LastName": "Doe",
    //    "Age": 36
    //  }


    Console.WriteLine(firstNameJson);
    //  {
    //    "FirstName": "John",    
    //  }        
}

public class SelectiveSerializer : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly string[] _fields;

    public SelectiveSerializer(string fields)
    {
        var fieldColl = fields.Split(',');
        _fields = fieldColl
            .Select(f => f.ToLower().Trim())
            .ToArray();
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        property.ShouldSerialize = o => _fields.Contains(member.Name.ToLower());

        return property;
    }
}

public class TestContract
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Without much effort, you could probably work this into your default mediatype formatter (in the pipeline) to look for a parameter in the request called 'fields' or whatever and then use the custom contract resolver if present, and then it would be seamless default behavior to limit fields if specified or serialize the entire object if not specified.

On the academic side, here is the justification:
Any modification to the data is considered a "view concern" which means, in an API, it should controlled by query parameters and accept header. In this case, the "representation" of the data is application/json and you've chose to "filter" the returned fields. All of this can (and should be, imo) be handled during serialization. So your "model" in this case will always be the full model vs. some subset of the model. The full model in this example contains first name, last name, and age. In reality, this could be hundreds of properties. If you want to allow the client to choose a subset of the complete model, this is how you could do it with selective serialization.

You can similar behaviors in graph apis. There, the default for large models is that you get an empty object if you don't specify fields, forcing the client to be very specific about what it asks for, which is great when payload size matters (e.g. mobile applications). And, there's nothing stopping from creating field presets like 'name' which could mean 'firstname, lastname' or 'all' which includes all properties.

I've never been a fan of having hundreds of data objects that all serve some ad hoc requirement for a data set that is used in 20 different contexts where some cases require more data while others require less. IMO if you have to go through the same process to get the data, whether it complete or not, you shouldn't waste your time creating additional objects to frame the data for the sake of the client, and this should help you achieve that.

Comment: I like the idea of your `SelectiveSerializer`; do you know if there is a library that does this? because going further with the idea one would like to specify subfields, say: `new SelectiveSerializer("firstname, mother.firstname, mother.age");`... sounds like a good separate project itself

Comment: apparently there is FlexJSON, that has an include and exclude method: `jsons = new JSONSerializer().include("name", "age", ...)`

Comment: Json.Net does it out of the box. You just need to implement their custom serializer. It's not very hard. I think the last time I tried it out, it took about 5 minutes and most of it was just figuring out what each of the 3 methods did. You don't have to implement all of it. I fed it a list property names and just compared each and short-circuited where they didn't match.

Answer (score 2):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Publication
{
    [Key]
    public int PublicationID { get; set; }
    public string PublicationTitle { get; set; }
    public string Frequency { get; set; }
    public DateTime NextIssueDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime SpaceDeadline { get; set; }
    public DateTime MaterialsDeadline { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]    
    public DateTime CreatedDt { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]    
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]    
    public DateTime UpdatedDt { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]    
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as Craig W. said you can use viewmodel ,also you can use anonymous type
(notice viewmodel is better way because you can use some utilities like automapper for mapping your property automatically)

Comment: The only problem with anonymous type is then the method can't return an `IQueryable<SomeType>`, it would have to be `dynamic`. That would work but it makes unit testing a real PITA.

Answer (score 1):

JsonIgnore annotation has worked for me

```
[JsonIgnore]  
public int Ranking { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://code-maze.com/data-shaping-aspnet-core-webapi/) is a great article (Dec 2019) on the subject. It offers a solution for data shaping by making use of [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netframework-4.8) and [Type Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection). The properties that the client requires can then be passed through the request as a query parameter (i.e. separated by a comma). The article also offers solution to the JSON Serialization problem.

Startup.cs file:

```
services.AddControllers(config =>
{
    config.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
    config.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
})
.AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()
.AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Answer (score -1):

+1 for Sinaesthetic's answer.
I just finished reading an article, about GraphQL which solves exactly this problem. You can define exactly which fields do you need in the same request. No need for creating new endpoints every single time, when the caller needs just a specific subset of the properties.
If you can do this in .NET WEB API too without creating new models and endpoints, with just a very little extra effort, why wouldn't you (instead of exchanging Web Api for GraphQL).

Actually his SelectiveSerializer could be upgarded with reflection, so if you want to define which props you need in
C#, you can do this by providing property expressions, so you don't have to worry about misstyping prop names.

I bet there are other solutions for this, but the basic concept is the most important that we can define which fields we need in our json without creating new models.

Comment: can you please provide improvised version if you can?

Comment: This appears to be commentary on another answer, rather than an answer of its own.