# Dynamic fields selection with ASP core API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

i want to let the user select the fields to be returned in the api response, someting like:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Result<BaseModel>>> GetData(
    [FromQuery] string[] fields,
    [FromService] IRepo repo)
{
   var dynamicSelecte = SomeResolver.BuildDynamicSelect<ModelType>(fields);

   var data = await repo.Models
       .Select(dynamicSelecte)
       .ToArrayAsync();

   return new BaseModel {
     Data = data
   };
}
```

is there any library that does this, I don't want to use GraphQL.

Comment: Would you like to create a custom contract resolver like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39906010/18789859)?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? @J.Common